# Printing pair of numbers using for loop - Python

Tags: python, printing, sum, integer, numbers

I am a beginner in python and I need some help with a case: I need to print pairs of numbers which are input from a for loop - for example

```
count_of_numbers = int(input())

for numbers in range(2*count_of_numbers):
    number = int(input())
```

Let's say we enter 3 2 1 4 5 0 4, I need to print the sum of the paired numbers - 3 + 2, 1 + 4 etc. Could anybody brighten me up with an idea on how exactly this is done?

Comment: what exactly is the input? `3 2 1 4 5 0 4` is not an integer

Comment: first you input 3, then 2 and so on so basically the input is always an int

Comment: Firstly their can't be 7 numbers entered, because whatever you enter as count_of_numbers, twice that number will always be even. And if `3` here is `count_of_numbers`, then I guess first sum of pairs will be, `2 + 1` and not `3 + 2`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I have actually made a mistake, the first number defines the length of the range so in this case it'd be 2*3, then the numbers should be adding up as following: 2+1, 4+5, 0+4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to keep much of your code:

```
count_of_numbers = int(input("Please enter the number of pairs: "))
  
for i in range(count_of_numbers):
    number1 = int(input("Number 1 = "))
    number2 = int(input("Number 2 = "))
    print ("Sum of " + str(number1) + " and " + str(number2) + " = " + \ 
            str(number1 + number2))
```

I made a few changes:

1. since the loop requests 2 inputs instead of one, the loop only runs up to `count_of_numbers`. I could have used "+ 1", but preferred to start at zero, as the variable `i` (formerly `numbers`) isn't used.
2. In order to guide the user running this program, I've added some text to the `input()` calls

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to add some input validation to ensure the user is inputting an integer:

```
def get_int_input(prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: Enter an integer, try again...')


def main() -> None:
    count_pairs = get_int_input('How many pairs will you like to add: ')
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, count_pairs + 1):
        a = get_int_input(f'Enter number {i}: ')
        b = get_int_input(f'Enter number {i + 1}: ')
        a_plus_b = a + b
        print(f'{a} + {b} = {a_plus_b}')
        total += a_plus_b
    print(f'Overall total = {total}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
How many pairs will you like to add: 3
Enter number 1: 2
Enter number 2: 1
2 + 1 = 3
Enter number 2: 4
Enter number 3: 5
4 + 5 = 9
Enter number 3: 0
Enter number 4: 4
0 + 4 = 4
Overall total = 16
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this solves your problem. Try this code in your code compiler. I hope you'll get your desired output.

```
count_of_numbers = int(input())
digits = []
for numbers in range(1, 2*count_of_numbers):
    number = int(input())
    digits.append(number)

for i in range(0, len(digits), 2):
    if (i + 1) >= len(digits):
        break
    print(digits[i] + digits[i+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Short and Sweet Solution. Check if you like.

you just have to enter the number and it will automatically add the alternate sum.

```
input_var = list(map(int,input("Enter The Numbers : ").split(' ')))
if len(input_var)%2 != 0:
    input_var.append(0)
for x in range(0,len(input_var),2):
    print(f"""The sum of {input_var[x]} and {input_var[x+1]} is : """,end=' ')
    print(input_var[x] + input_var[x+1])
```

The Output is below:

```
Enter The Numbers : 3 2 1 4 5 0 4
The sum of 3 and 2 is :  5
The sum of 1 and 4 is :  5
The sum of 5 and 0 is :  5
The sum of 4 and 0 is :  4
```

> If the input length is even then well and fine, if not then it will automatically add last digit with 0

Hope you will like it.

Thank you :)

Comment: Lists should not be included unfortunately, otherwise it's a great solution

Comment: Sure, You can Just edit accordingly and give the input and the operation will be same.!
Hope it will help.!